# How I can store the indexes where a number appears on a list of Prolog?

Tags: indexing, prolog

For example:
`positions (X, L, R):- 
.`

Where:

1. X is the number that I am looking for.
2. L is a list of many numbers.
3. R is the list that will store the indexes where X appears

I got this, but it doesn´t "return" a list, it just gives me individual results:

```
pos(X,[X|_],0).
pos(,[],):- !,fail. pos(X,[_|R],Pos):- pos(X,R,Pos1), Pos is Pos1+1.
```

Comment: Have you tried anything yet?

Comment: well I got this, but it doesn´t "return" a list, it just gives me individual results:

`pos(X,[X|_],0).

pos(_,[],_):-

!,fail.

pos(X,[_|R],Pos):-

pos(X,R,Pos1),

Pos is Pos1+1.`

`?- pos(0,[1,2,0,1,0],R).
R = 2 ;
R = 4 ;
false.`

Comment: That's perfect! SO is all about posting code that does not work yet.

Comment: You are so right!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have access to `nth0/3` or `nth1/3`, it can be used to "find" the positions of an element in a list. For example:

```
?- List = [0,1,2,3,0,4,5,0], nth0(N, List, 0).
List = [0, 1, 2, 3, 0, 4, 5, 0],
N = 0 ;
N = 4 ;
N = 7.
```

All you need is to collect all answers in a list. Just use `bagof/3`:

```
?- List = [0,1,2,3,0,4,5,0], bagof(N, nth0(N, List, 0), Ns).
List = [0, 1, 2, 3, 0, 4, 5, 0],
Ns = [0, 4, 7].
```

You can define it as a predicate like this:

```
positions(X, L, R) :-
    bagof(N, nth0(N, L, X), R).
```

Unlike the other solutions, you can use this to find the positions of *any* element in the list upon backtracking:

```
?- positions(X, [0,1,2,0,2], R).
X = 0,
R = [0, 3] ;
X = 1,
R = [1] ;
X = 2,
R = [2, 4].
```

If you don't want to use `nth0/3`, just go ahead and use your own definition of `pos/3`, just make sure it does what it should. See for example the [answer to the third of the 99 Prolog problems](http://www.ic.unicamp.br/~meidanis/courses/mc336/2009s2/prolog/problemas/p03.pl): it is a straight-forward implementation of `nth1/3`. You just have to change the 1 to 0 to get 0-based indices. It is almost identical to what you already had (as shown in your question).

Answer (score 0):

I think you need a index and creare `R` accumulating the matching indexes.

By example

```
positionH(_, _, [], []).

positionH(I, X, [Y | Tl], Tr):-
  Y \= X, 
  Ip1 is I+1,
  positionH(Ip1, X, Tl, Tr).

positionH(I, X, [X | Tl], [I | Tr]):-
  Ip1 is I+1,
  positionH(Ip1, X, Tl, Tr).

position(X, L, R):-
  positionH(0, X, L, R).
```

Answer (score 0):

You can modify your code like this:

```
positions(X, L, R) :- positions(X, L, R, 1).

positions(_, [], [], _).
positions(X, [X|T], [I|R], I) :- plus(I, 1, N), positions(X, T, R, N).
positions(X, [Y|T], R, I) :- X \= Y, plus(I, 1, N), positions(X, T, R, N).
```

[Demo.](http://ideone.com/ZnV80S)

The `positions/3` clause is there to add the current index `I` to `positions/4` rule.

The three clauses of `positions/4` are as follows:

- The first, base, clause is for an empty list
- The second clause is for matching the initial element to `X`
- The third clause is to move on to the next element when there is no match (i.e. `X \= Y`).

Comment: This is what I was looking for, the only change I did is on the initial index, because it had to be 0 but I already modified this code. TU!!

Comment: Does this work if you query it with a free variable in the first argument?

Comment: @Boris I do not see it being a requirement.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight Yes, you are right, but since it is so easy to do it, using standard predicates, it is strange not to. Prolog is a high-level programming language, and exactly this kind of use (non-deterministic predicate that works in different modes + bagof) is one of its strengths.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight This is without going into the several reasons why I couldn't bring myself to give your answer a +1 (and I usually don't spare the plus votes). I could go into it if you think you are interested.

Comment: @Boris Although I definitely agree that Prolog is a high-level language, and that learning about built-in predicates is important, I think OP is at an early stages of learning the language, when understanding the Clocksin&Mellish style of coding up the most basic things is more important than learning the library. It goes without saying that it is only my opinion, which can very well be incorrect, and is also subject to change by sufficient argumentation :-)

Comment: @dasblinkenlight (sorry for spamming you with comments) There is often the choice between answering a beginner's question and dishing out advice. You answered the question; I thought in this particular case it might be better to give advice on how to approach it differently.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight The thing is, Prolog has changed, and people know more about how to write code in Prolog than back then. Keep in mind that my reaction right now might be influenced by a traumatic experience in university, where Prolog (of the Clocksin&Melish kind) was forced down my throat. It took me a few years to recover and to realize it is not such a silly language after all :(

Comment: @Boris That's a fair point. Admittedly, my contacts with the world of Prolog development have been rather limited for the last 20+ years, so I missed a lot of developments, such as addition of object-orientation to Prolog. To me, the language remains a C&M plus much better libraries, which, I gather, is a rather narrow view these days :-)